# Grails project: Gorm or JPA/Hibernate annotations for legacy db mapping?

Tags: java, jpa, mapping, grails-orm, legacy-database

In a grails app, I have to create a bunch of grails domain classes mapped to a very old db.

This very old db is using a lots of "funky" unreadable names for tables and columns.
These tables contains (too) often (too) many columns.

I was thinking of using the static mapping for all the relationship and using the JPA annotations for the columns names (almost all columns needs to be renamed and the mapping section will be elephantine)

Is this kind of mix is possible ?
If yes, is it something that I must avoid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-grails07158/index.html